# How to solve $0=1+\frac{x}{3!}+ \frac{x^2}{5!}+ \frac{x^3}{7!}+...$?

Tags: analysis

When I take some calculation, I find an equation
$$
0=1+\frac{x}{3!}+ \frac{x^2}{5!}+ \frac{x^3}{7!}+...
$$ 
Obviously, when $x=0$, the right part is positive. And when $x=-1$, the right part is negative, so, there should be a root in $[-1,0]$. But I fail to calculate it.

Besides, I feel there should be infinitely many roots, how to present them ?

Comment: It seems like the right hand side is just $\frac 1{\sqrt x}\text{sinh}(\sqrt x)$, where $\text{sinh}$ is the hyperbolic sine. EDIT: this would only apply for $x>0$, so I'm not sure it's of much help.

Comment: @SangchulLee, I think you should post that as an answer so that OP can accept it (as it seems to be correct and complete to me) :)

Comment: @IsaacRen, I migrated my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Restricting our attention to real $x$, note that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!}
= \begin{cases}
\frac{\sinh\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}},&x>0;\\
1,&x=0;\\
\frac{\sin\sqrt{-x}}{\sqrt{-x}},&x<0.
\end{cases}$$

So it vanishes exactly when $x=-\pi^2n^2$ for $n=1,2,\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the rhs is positive if $x >0$. So consider instead
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{\sin \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$ So, if you want that to be zero, you need to solve $\sin \left(\sqrt{x}\right)=0$